# Send iMessage using WatchOS App

Tags: share, watchkit, imessage

I have a string value in a WatchOS 2 app, and want to send an iMessage text using the value. An example of this is in the Workflow watch app, where the send message action results in the following screenshot:

[image]

I can't find any frameworks or url schemes that will work on WatchOS, so how do I do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can send your "**string**" by enabling the Capabilites of group on both iMessage and watch target and sharing by the Userdefaults among the Targets(iMessagge and Watch OS).

> ```
> //Watch OS sharing **String**
>  func sharedUserInfo() {
>         if let userDefaults =  UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.watch.app.com" ) {
>             userDefaults.set( stringObj as AnyObject, forKey: "string")
>             userDefaults.synchronize()
>             }
>
>         }
>
> //iMessage extracting the info 
>  func sharedInfo() {
>         if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.watch.app.com") {
>             let stringObj = userDefaults.string(forKey: "string")
>            }
>
>        }
> ```

*So you can send the **string** from watch OS to iMessage*